# AngularJS Socketio factory error i cant fix

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, socket.io

My Factory

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('socketFac',function($rootscope) {
    var socket = io.connect();
    return {
      on: function (eventName, callback) {
        socket.on(eventName, function () {  
          var args = arguments;
          $rootScope.$apply(function () {
            callback.apply(socket, args);
          });
        });
      },
      emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
        socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
          var args = arguments;
          $rootScope.$apply(function () {
            if (callback) {
              callback.apply(socket, args);
            }
          });
        })
      }
    };
});
```

My App

```
angular.module('myApp', [
'ngRoute',
'appRoutes',
'anasayfaCtrl',
'girisCtrl',
'kayitCtrl',
'indexCtrl',
'btcCtrl',
'ltcCtrl',
'bchCtrl',
'profilCtrl',
'cikisCtrl'
```

]);

And the Error is

```
[$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$injector/unpr?p0=socketProvider%20%3C-%20socket%20%3C-%20IndexController
```

I want to use my factory for all my socket events from my other controllers etc. 
My app is at IndexController file both in same app.js

Answer (score 0):

First, try by fixing the spelling for function parameter ($rooScope). 
If not get the result then please try with the following (injecting $rootScope).

```
  angular.module('myApp')
 .factory('socketFac',['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    var socket = io.connect();
    return {
      on: function (eventName, callback) {
        socket.on(eventName, function () {  
          var args = arguments;
          $rootScope.$apply(function () {
            callback.apply(socket, args);
          });
        });
      },
      emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
        socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
          var args = arguments;
          $rootScope.$apply(function () {
            if (callback) {
              callback.apply(socket, args);
            }
          });
        })
      }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I fixed that the problem is $rootscope and changed that to $rootScope everything works fine thanks.